# How to obtain event logs for particular application from Windows Event Viewer

Tags: c#, event-log, eventlog-source

I'm implementing an application that works similar to Windows Event Viewer. I mean that it monitors System Event Logs and Application Event logs with the help of `EventLog` and `EventLogEntry` classes.

Is it possible to obtain Application Event logs for particular process (for example Chrome)?

In the list of log entries I can find different Sources like `"Winlogon"`, `"WMI"`, `"MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS"` and so on, but not the name of particular app.

Answer (score 1):

Application name is not recorded in the event log entries. In fact, even the sources are not a reliable indicator, because you can write your own message with any source you want.

Comment: So it seems to be impossible to monitor if some critical errors or warnings in third-party application happened, doesn't it? If I understand correctly it is possible only when this third-party app writes logs to Event Viewer itself.

Comment: Windows error reporting writes an event log entry, if application had a hard crash and "send error report to microsoft" appears. You can search that message for process name. However, many applications have their own error reporting tools that may not write anything to windows event log.